# imap_search and subject command

Tags: php

Hello for all and happy holidays!!

I have a code for connect my inbox mail. Is this...

```
$host = '{'.SMTP_HOST.':143/novalidate-cert}INBOX';
$entrada = imap_open($host, SMTP_USER , SMTP_PASS);

$emails_mejora = imap_search($entrada, 'SUBJECT "Envíanos el tamaño de la imágen"', SE_UID, , 'UTF-8');
```

The subject contains utf8 characters and show 0 results. With other subjects without utf8 characters works fine...

Please any help

Thanks ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@sergio, use `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");` at the top of your php file to set Character Set in UTF-8 format

You should use collation " `utf8_general_ci` " in database table field if u used special characters.